# как закинуть параметри в методах с типом void c#

Tags: c#, методы, null, void

я делаю простую програму для подщета линейньіх уравнений c ООП. Я написал 3 метода, которьіе вьідают разньіе значения, и один метод, которьій вьізивает все другие. Также он проверяет (a и b) на равенство к нулю, и при вьізове метода, мне вьідает ошьібку  cannot convert from void to bool.
Я думаю проблема в том, что я накинул параметрьі в void метод.

Мой гавнокод:

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace lesson1
{
    class Program
    {
        class InputIntegers
        {
            protected decimal _a;

            public decimal A
            {
                get { return _a; }
                set { _a = value; }
            }
            protected decimal _b;

            public decimal B
            {
                get { return _b; }
                set { _b = value; }
            }

        }
        class IntegersChecker : InputIntegers
        {
            private decimal A_IsNotNull(decimal a, decimal b)
            {
                return b / a;
            }
            private decimal A_AndB_IsNull()
            {
                Random integer = new Random();
                int randomValue = integer.Next(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue);
                return randomValue;
            }
            private void A_IsNullAndB_IsNotNull()
            {
                throw new Exception("Рівняння розвязку немає");
            }
            public void Checker(decimal a, decimal b)
            {
                if (a != 0)
                {
                    A_IsNotNull(a,b);
                }
                if (a == 0 && b == 0)
                {
                    A_AndB_IsNull();
                }
                if (a == 0 && b != 0)
                {
                    A_IsNullAndB_IsNotNull();
                }
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            
            try
            {
                decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                decimal b = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                IntegersChecker integersChecker = new IntegersChecker {
                    A = a,
                    B = b
                };
                integersChecker.Checker(integersChecker.Checker(integersChecker.A, integersChecker.B));//Проблема при вьізове
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Введи нормальне значення");
            }
        }
        
    }

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте return в метод Checker и всего делов

Comment: А разве можно возвращат значение с void метода?

Comment: Так сделайте не void. У вас почему-то метод принимает на вход числа, а вы передаёт void. Может лишний integersChecker.Checker?